# XmlDocument.Load returns 403 but curl url returns 200

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to populate an XmlDocument via the follow

```
       var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
       xmlDoc.Load("https://somewhere.com/stuff.xml");
```

The load returns a 403, however if I curl the the url or just visit in browser it all works.

Comment: Could be that your site you are attempting to download from is filtering something based on how XmlDocument is attempting to call the url. (Perhaps user agent or something).  You will most likely need to create an actual httpclient or webrequest call and download your xml that way.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx). You are using the Load(String) method and your string is no valid XML. XmlDocument.Load(String) does not download the xml file when providing an URL.

Comment: No, .Load() wants a url

Comment: yes actually your link to MSDN contradicts what you are stating. Load can accept a URL and download the corresponding xml. However loadxml method expects the string to be some form of xml.